# Turning SQL Distinct data into readable list in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some custom tables in Wordpress that store information about people, linked to a post, and I want to be able to generate a summary of the data, specifically, a sentence along the lines of:

```
"This post mentions 4 surnames: Brown, Jones, Robinson and Smith"
```

I currently pull out the data as follows:

```
$surnames = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT distinct lastname 
  FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."people 
  WHERE post_id='$post_id' 
  ORDER BY lastname asc");
```

Which returns an array of objects as follows:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ([lastname] => Brown ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => Jones ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => Robinson ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => Smith ) 
)
```

So at the moment, I just do this:

```
foreach ($surnames as $surname) {$summary .= $surname->lastname.', ';}
```

which returns:

```
Brown, Jones, Robinson, Smith,
```

Clearly not acceptable.

Is there any standard php function that can do this, AND that will work on an array of objects?  I'd imagine this is a common problem, and I'm trying to avoid reinventing the wheel if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Watch with `implode($separator, $array)` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

But this is only for arrays so you might have to find a walkaround.

Comment: Thanks, I tried implode, and although it does create a comma seperated list, and solves the problem of the last comma, it doesn't add in the final 'and'.

Answer (score 0):

If you were returning your the data from your database as array rather than as object, you could use PHP 5.5's new array_column() function:

```
$summary = implode(
    ', ',
    array_column(
        $surnames,
        'lastname'
    )
);
```

Modifying your query call to

```
$surnames = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT distinct lastname 
  FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."people 
  WHERE post_id='$post_id' 
  ORDER BY lastname asc",
  ARRAY_A
);
```

will alow you to return an associative array rather than an object for each record

And you can use something like:

```
function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject) {
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);
    if($pos !== false) {
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

to replace the last `,` with `and`